# How can I get Error free W3C Validate Bootstrap CSS3 code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

My client want to W3 Validate HTML5 & CSS3 code. I want to use bootstrap 3.3.4 on it. But when I include Bootstrap and check at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ 32 errors and 142 warnings found.

> W3C CSS Validator results for
>   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css (CSS
>   level 3) Sorry! We found the following errors (32)

How can I get error free W3C Validate Bootstrap CSS3 code?

Comment: who validates plugins... and tell your client you can only validate your personal code... or something. dont go about validatiing bootstrap. if there are issues with it, check their github.

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast Cause invalid markup by other people's code can cause you issues.

Answer (score 2):

W3C Validator will always throw warnings and errors with bootstrap and many other frameworks. If you(or your client) want(/wants) a clean result, just check an own code (error free) and use the given code in the website. I'm sorry, but that seems to me the only solution.

Hope it helps. If it does, +1.